# Android app that connects to a coin collector

Tags: android, hardware

I am trying to find a way to develop an Android app that connects to a coin connector.  How would I get the Android app to recognize that a coin was inserted into the hardware?

Similar to the setup in this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7FowiQbNVA

Comment: This is a very general question! You have to be more specific.

Comment: Okay. Basically I want the app to be able to recognize that a coin was inserted before it allows the user to use certain functions of the app.  I am not looking for someone to write the code for me.  I merely want someone to point me out towards what tools/hardware there is out there that would allow me to connect a coin collector with an android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a general view about what you have to do,

First of all, you have to receive data from your coin device. Therefore you have to talk to a hardware specialist who can change this event to data, maybe using a USB cable communication or a BlueTooth or Wifi connection.

Then you can received this event data from Android OS and use it on your device. You may also require to use NDK and some C development.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Right now i'm looking at something that's like Coin collector -> Arduino -> android app.  But I wonder if there's a better alternative to this set up

Comment: Then I thinks you can ask your question in Arduino community: http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: It was very useful for pointing me into the right direction,  thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that 